# How to centralize primefaces menubar?

Tags: java, css, jsf, primefaces

I need to centralize the primefaces menubar. I tried this: `<p:menubar style="text-align: center !important">` but it did not work.

Please, help!

Comment: do you want to center the contents or the menubar itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To center elements in the menubar (aka center the content), I think you would this because the bar is 100% width.
In the facelet add the *"styleclass"* attribute to the menubar:

```
<p:menubar styleClass="centeredMenuBar">
```

and in the css file just add:

```
.centeredMenuBar.ui-menubar {
    text-align: center;
}

.centeredMenuBar .ui-menu-list {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Center menubar, not the contents**(modified from primefaces showcase):

```
    <p:menubar style="width: 100px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
        <p:submenu label="Blah" icon="ui-icon-document" />
        <p:submenu label="Blah2" icon="ui-icon-document" />
        <p:menuitem value="Quit" url="http://www.primefaces.org"
            icon="ui-icon-close" />
    </p:menubar>
```