# How to distribute p:menuitems in p:menubar accordingly?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I have a `<p:menubar>` with some `<p:menuitem>`s to display a horizontal menu to users. This is my current simplified code (removed internationalization and other non-related stuff):

```html
<p:menubar id="mbrMainMenu" styleClass="centeredMenuBar">
    <p:menuitem value="Home" outcome="/index.xhtml" />
    <p:submenu label="Product Catalog">
        <!-- some menuitems here... -->
    </p:submenu>
    <p:submenu label="Make your own design">
        <!-- some menuitems here... -->
    </p:submenu>
</p:menubar>
```

Code above gets displayed like this:

```
 _____________________________________________________ _____________________________________
|        |                   |                        |                                     |
|  Home  |  Product Catalog  |  Make your own design  |         <wasted whitespace>         |
|________|___________________|________________________|_____________________________________|
```

I'm searching for a look n' feel where the `<p:menuitem>` and `<p:submenu>` are centered and the width of each one is distributed accordingly (I'm not very skilled with CSS):

```
 _______________________________________________________________________________
|                  |                           |                                |
|       Home       |      Product Catalog      |      Make your own design      |
|__________________|___________________________|________________________________|
```

I've found how to center them using a custom CSS `centeredMenuBar` (taken from here: [How to centralize primefaces menubar?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13766446/1065197)), but now I'm having a hard time trying to distribute the menu items along the menu bar, they are all stick.

```
 __________________________________________________________________ ____________
|            |        |                   |                        |            |
|  <wasted>  |  Home  |  Product Catalog  |  Make your own design  |  <wasted>  |
|____________|________|___________________|________________________|____________|
```

I've tried this but failed:

1. Creating a custom CSS to override the ui-menu-item and ui-menu-parent PrimeFaces styles:

   ```
   .ui-menu-item .ui-menu-parent {
       width: auto;
   }
   ```
2. Using `style="width: auto;"` directly in the `<p:menuitem>` and `<p:submenu>`.

Any idea how to accomplish this?

---

This is what I have:

[image]

This is what I want (last picture edited in paint just to show the last form):

[image]

Comment: To be sure: 1/ Do you want the whole bar to be full width or just the length of text plus some padding? 2/ Does "Home" and "Very long text" need to have equal width or "depends of the length of text + some fixed padding"?

Comment: Something close can be realized using `inline-block`'s or `table-cell`, but getting the vertical separators mid-way between the text elements is hard to do unless you add some extra mark-up.  What are you willing to consider?

Comment: @FelipeAls 1/ I want to maintain the whole bar to be full width to the page. 2/ Currently, they have different width, I wish there is a way they could have same width and be distributed accordingly dynamically in case I need to add more options in the menu. By now, they are all distributed and centered but there's a big space of difference between the options and the Window Borders.

Comment: @MarcAudet I have all the freedom to add and edit code as long as *it works* i.e. the clients and users see the UI and are comfortable.

Comment: Would my previous answer about [css table-cell equal width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525744/css-table-cell-equal-width/10526275#10526275) be a suitable solution then? The value of `table-layout` changes the algorithm used by browsers from "adapt to text" to "adapt to what author set" (and table layout - in CSS - will render items on a single row, same height "cells", very flexible whatever the number of "cells").

Comment: @FelipeAls I could give it a try, but unsure if it will work because the `<p:menuitem>` are displayed in form of `<li>` rather than `<div>`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried this and this works properly for me, here has no waste of space. You can try this.

This is my `<p:menubar>`. Note that I'm using `styleClass="menu"` instead of `centeredBar` as proposed in your current solution.

```
<p:menubar styleClass="menu">
    <p:menuitem value="Home"></p:menuitem>
    <p:menuitem value="Apply Leave"></p:menuitem>
    <p:menuitem value="Calender"></p:menuitem>
    <p:submenu label="New">  
       <p:menuitem value="Project" url="#" />  
       <p:menuitem value="Other" url="#" />  
    </p:submenu>
</p:menubar>
```

And this is the css I have written

```
div.menu{
text-align: center;
}
.menu div.ui-menubar {
text-align: center;
}
.menu .ui-menu-list{
width:100%;
display: inline-flex;
}
div.menu>ul.ui-menu-list>li>a{
width: 100%;
}
div.menu>ul.ui-menu-list>li{
width: 100%;
}
.ui-menuitem-text{
float: none!important;
}
```

Comment: This worked but only for all `<p:menuitem>`s, not for `<p:submenu>`.

Comment: Sorry I am not getting you. is this fulfilling your requirement  `"I'm searching for a look n' feel where the <p:menuitem> and <p:submenu> are centered and the width of each one is distributed accordingly"`

Comment: Yes, I've tried this and didn't work as expected. I'm not sure if the fault is the other CSS. I'll try again and let you know.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing ? Wastage of space on both ends of menuBar or manues under submenu's width are not same as parent(submenu)?

Comment: Waste of space on both ends of menuBar.

Comment: can you post a snapshot please? with mouse hover.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza Question is clear. In my case out put is exactly what you want. One thing, have you changed your `<p:menubar>'s` css into `menu`? because I set css attribute named `menu` in my answer.

Comment: I guess that's my current mistake. I'll try one more time.

Comment: I made a rookie mistake. It works now, thanks. By the way, it would be great to edit your question to add that I should remove the `centeredMenuBar` class and use the `menu` one instead.

Comment: You are welcome. So please edit your `cssClass` attribute's value into `menu` in your question.

Comment: Nope I must not do that, note that I've used the `centeredMenuBar` class from another Q/A linked in my question :).

Answer (score -1):

Setting the margin-left and margin-right as shown below helped in my case to stretch the menu items spread out evenly across the length of the menubar.

```
.ui-menubar .ui-menuitem-text{
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 3px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
```

Hope it helps someone looking for an alternate solution.